# Build problems with Visual C++ project after checking in and checking out from CVS

Tags: windows, visual-c++, 64-bit, cvs, solution

I am building a cross platform product and one of the requirements is across windows(win32,AMD64 and IA61). The product as is relatively simple CLI but we have a separate build team who checks out the code from CVS and build in separate build environments. I am able to build succesfully(using Visual C++ 2005) in one platform(AMD machine). But once I check in the code, check out the build fails.

The cause of the build failure is because the include library paths are wrongly specified in the property sheets. Specifically the output file folder under the Linker in property pages are specified wrongly. So these libraries get built in a different folder from where the other projects are expecting them.

However along with the source I check in the .sln files (and later .vcproj files) also everytime. Morover if I open the .sln file in the folder where the build is not succeeding, there is no difference between the one where I could succesfully build(pre check in). In fact using windiff I could not see any difference between the two build folders (except some .ncb and cvs log files).

So any idea what is going on? Where does VC++ 2005 take the include directories take the output folder path from if not from .sln?  Is CVS somehow interfering with the process? Anything else I could try out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. I have checked out .vcproj files as well. As I mentioned Windiff shows no difference between the folders.

Comment: Just to clarify the basic query I have is does VC++ store the property sheet data for a solution in the .sln file only? Or are there any other files required?

Comment: Update- If I copy the folder to another place the build works fine. I am almost convinced that this has something to do with the cvs checkins/checkouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update the problem was resolved. The root cause is the .vcproj files were not getting checked in CVS!! This is where the individual project settings were stored(I was under the impression that this is done in .sln files).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be that after you have changed the settings in one build configuration (for example x86-Release) but forgotten to change them for another configuration (for example ia64-Debug), and when configuration changes, you have this problem.

Another thing that I would check on your place is project dependencies. If those are set in the right way VS will look for project output exactly where it is outputted, even when you change the output folder.

Comment: Regarding #1 the problem currently occurs within the same configuration(release|x64). I check in x64 and check out and rebuild only x64. 

#2 Project dependencies are same for all the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any binary files checked in as ASCII?

The round trip to and from CVS can corrupt binary files that are incorrectly marked as ASCII because CVS performs character processing on ASCII files (e.g. to give you the correct end of line codes for your OS). Corruption can occur even in an all Windows environment.

See the Binary section in the [CVS FAQ](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/wiki/CVS%20FAQ) for more information.

Comment: I dont think so. In any case the reason the build is failing is because the dependant libraries are getting built in a different folder from the one specified in the main program.